# Mysql update table with pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a wraper code to that updates SQL table with pandas DataFrame. I found somewhere that this query would be fine

```
query = \
        """
        UPDATE 
            target 
        SET
            {column_statement}
        FROM
            {table} AS target
        INNER JOIN
        (VALUES
            {value_statement}
        ) 
        AS 
            src ({column_str_list})
        ON {join_statement};
        """
```

Unfortunately, it does not work with MySQL. The situation is as follows : I have a DataFrame and I want to update SQL table with new values from columns `x,y` (can be one or a few) based on matching values from columns `a,b,c` (can be one of a few).

Any idea how can I rewrite this to mysql syntax? I am using `sqlalchemy` btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to update SQL table with new values from columns x,y (can be one or a few) based on matching values from columns a,b,c (can be one of a few).

The SQL code you are using does not look like valid MySQL syntax, and seems overcomplicated compared to what you are trying to achieve.

I believe that your requirement can be summarized as the following in pseudo-SQL :

```
UPDATE mytable SET {assignments} WHERE {conditions}
```

Details :

- `{conditions}` picks the records that will be updated : could be `a = ? AND b = ? AND c = ?`, or just `a = ?`, or anything else that you need.
- `{assignments}` sets the values : eg: `x = ?, y = ?`, or `x = ?`, and so one

Example : set `x` to 3 and `y` to 5 where `a` is 1

```
UPDATE mytable SET x = 3, y = 5 WHERE a = 1
```

Comment: thanks @GMB! The code you wrote will update one row at a time. If I want to update 100 rows in single query can I just repeat what you wrote 100 times (with semicolon at the end)?

Comment: @Bociek : it does not update one row, it updates all records that satisfy the condition(s) you provide...

Comment: I have a mysql `user` table and a pandas `df_user` dataframe. They are all the same, except one column(`register_time`). I want to update the mysql table with the df, to make they are all the same. Is there a better way besides iterate updating through the `user_id`?